# Logging sent to STDOUT/STDERR on Google Container Engine pods not showing in Cloud Logging

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

From what I understand any output sent to `STDOUT`/`STDERR` from the Docker processes running in a GKE pod should show up in Cloud Logging if enabled.

My Ruby on Rails app is configured to print to `STDOUT` which I have verified by running `kubectl logs <POD_NAME>` and seen the values for each HTTP request as I expect. However even though I have ensured that I have enabled Cloud Logging I do not see these same values in Logging. Is there another step necessary?

SSH-ing into the container I see `gcr.io/google_containers/fluentd-gcp:1.15` running as well as a pause container PORTS `k8s_POD.6d00e006_fluentd-cloud-logging-gke-web`.

Version of the pod running the Rails app:

```
...  MASTER_VERSION  MASTER_IP       MACHINE_TYPE      NODE_VERSION  NUM_NODES  STATUS
...  1.1.8           104.196.24.206  g1-small          1.1.8         1          RUNNING
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry if you already have, but did you switch the service selector in the logs viewer to the "Container Engine" option? It's the dropdown labeled with the number 3 in [this screenshot](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs_viewer#the_viewer_interface). Container Engine logs won't be shown if it's set to any other service.

If you've already set that properly and aren't seeing any logs, then could you check the logs for the fluentd container and let me know what they have in them? You can either run `docker logs <container-id>` on the node or `kubectl logs <pod-name> --namespace=kube-system`.

Comment: Hmm, might have been an issue in the Cloud console. Before the "Container Engine" option wasn't showing up. This morning it was there and for logs I was checking for last night when I couldn't see them. Thanks for the commands.